# import csv file into postgres table based on some key

Tags: postgresql, csv

I want to import one CSV file that is having only two columns as 'name' and 'details'.

In my postgres sql i have a table called 'Person' which is having 8 column including 'name' and 'details'.

Now what i want is to import the csv file into Person table and when the name column of csv matches the Person name column it should import the details column into Person .

That is based on key match and the key is name and value is details.

Is there any other way possible.

Comment: Import into temp table, and then do the logic in SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to create a temporary table and from there populate the `person` table with a simple update query.

Data Sample

```
CREATE TABLE public.person(
  name text,
  details text,
  something_else text);

INSERT INTO person (name) VALUES 
('foo'),('bar');

CREATE TABLE public.tmp_person(
  name text,
  details text);
```

CSV file content:

```
name, details
foo, det1
bar, det2
```

Importing the csv file into `tmp_person`, e.g. via `psql`:

```
$ cat file.csv | psql -d mydb -U myuser -c "COPY tmp_person FROM STDIN CSV HEADER"
```

Then update your `person` table:

```
UPDATE person SET details = tmp.details
FROM tmp_person tmp WHERE tmp.name = person.name;
```

In the end the table `person` will have the `details` from the csv file, so you might wanna `DROP TABLE tmp_person`.

```
SELECT * FROM person;
 name | details | something_else 
------+---------+----------------
 foo  |  det1   | 
 bar  |  det2   | 
(2 Zeilen)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, your table has > 2 fields, but your CSV file has only two, so like this:

```
create table person (
  blah
  blah
  name text,
  details text,
  blah
  blah
)
```

person.csv:

```
name,details
Hambone,Where Ya Been?
Luke,Skywalker
```

If this is the case, you can specify the fields in your `copy` command:

```
copy person (name, details)
from '/var/tmp/person.csv'
with null as '' csv header;
```

Comment: Yes , you are right, but my problem is when the name of person table matches the name in the CSV file then details of that name from csv file should be dumped into Person table details column, else it should not.